# jump scroll with redirect to another page of same blog on blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a blog. i want to do if some one click on specific link. he should be jump scroll at specific point on same page. and then after some sec he should be auto redirect on other page of same blog/redirect to other blog. please also give example website address too.
I have this code.

Script is Like:

```
  function jumpScroll(){
   window.scroll(0,150);
  }
```

HTML is like:

```
  <a href="javascript:jumpScroll()"> Scroll Page </a>
```

Comment: _i have this code_ where??

Comment: here is code http://i.stack.imgur.com/B4HqR.png

Comment: you should post the code here not the image of the code.

Comment: You should put that here too :)

Comment: i am new here. i tried to put but getting error so that's why. plz ans the question ang giv me code with example and instruction

Comment: @nik1993 : check the final updated answer.this may solve your all problem.

Comment: @VaibhavJain but it redirect all links to same page can u give me another so that every link will redirect specific page

Comment: @nik1993: see the last part of the updated answer that will redirect you to different pages with different links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

**To being scrolling automatically** when the page loads, add the following code to the body tag:

```
<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

The link is Like:

```
 <a href="javascript:pageScroll()">Scroll Page</a>
```

**Scroll Directly to a Particular Point:**

Use the scroll() method to jump to a particular point on the page.Target position specify in the form of pixels.

```
function jumpScroll() {
window.scroll(0,150); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
}
```

Link is Like:

```
 <a href="javascript:jumpScroll()">Jump to another place on the page</a>
```

**For moving to the next page:**

```
function jumpScroll() {
window.scroll(0,150); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
    window.location.replace("http://page2.html");
}
```

**For moving to the specific page:**

you are suppose to call the different functions in each link like:

```
 <a href="javascript:jumpScroll1()">jump to page1</a>
 <a href="javascript:jumpScroll2()">Jump to page2</a>
 <a href="javascript:jumpScroll3()">Jump to page3</a>
```

script is Like:

```
   function jumpScroll1() {
window.scroll(0,150); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
    window.location.replace("http://page1.html");
}


function jumpScroll2() {
window.scroll(0,250); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
    window.location.replace("http://page2.html");
}


function jumpScroll3() {
window.scroll(0,350); // horizontal and vertical scroll targets
    window.location.replace("http://page3.html");
}
```

This works fine for me.

Reference Link: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

Comment: but i also want to redirect after that scolling to another page

Comment: @nik1993 : check the second part thats work fine for me.i am doing exactly same as you.for jump to the other target place the link should be at the different place.

Comment: yes it works I have done that but after scroll user must be redirect to another blog page

Comment: ok for that just add this line to your javascript code after window.scroll(); window.location.replace("The link of the page where you want to move");

Comment: @nik1993 :  check the final updated answer.this may solve your all problem.

Comment: @Vaibhav Jain :I hope you are going to get a tick for your effort, good answer

Comment: YUpee It's works thaks a lot but it redirect all links to same page can u give me another  so that every link will redirect specific page

Comment: @nik1993: see the last part of the updated answer that will redirect you to different pages with different links.