# jQuery slider with specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I'm working on a jQuery slider for my website. And I only want people to scroll to a few specific values, (for example 1900, 1920, 1960, 1975, 1976).

I tried everything but nothing works!

I also want the values to work as links, like if people scroll to 1920 it will redirect them to another page.

Here's the code

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1900,
      max: 2013,
      value: 1900,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

And this is the html:

```
<label for="amount">Year:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#000; font-weight:bold; background:none;" /><br /><br />
                <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    var araObj = new Array( 1900, 1920, 1960, 1975, 1976 );

    $(".slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: araObj.length,
            value: 0,
            create: function() {
                $(this).children().addClass("ui-corner-all");
                $(this).append($('<span></span>').css("left","0%").addClass("slider-digit").text(0));
                for (i=0;i<=araObj.length;i++)
                {
                    $(this).append($('<span></span>').css("left",((i+1)*(100/araObj.length))+"%").addClass("slider-digit").text(araObj[i]));
                };
            }
        });

    console.log(araObj);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9kbv/440/)

Comment: Works perfectly on an iPhone and iPad? Doesn't for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

[jump scroll with redirect to another page of same blog on blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605316/jump-scroll-with-redirect-to-another-page-of-same-blog-on-blogger)

this is similar as you are looking for

Comment: I think you mean something else. I'm talking about a slider as you see here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

Answer (score 0):

Remember, think carefully about the type of slider you are using. A number of slider implementations simply do not work on mobile devices and tablets. As an example, the answer above does not work on an iPhone or iPad.

A solution that may be usable can be found here:

http://touchpunch.furf.com

There are a number of examples and demos - they seem to be touch friendly. I am not sure if they will incorporate new page / links by default.

I hope that helps.